# Checking if a Binary Tree is Balanced

Tags: java, binary-tree

I saw the question in a book (Cracking the Coding Interview).
The suggested code is:

```
public boolean isBalanced(Node root) {

    if(root == null)
        return true;

    int leftHeight = getHeight(root.left);
    System.out.println("left height: " + leftHeight);
    int rightHeight = getHeight(root.right);
    System.out.println("right height: " + rightHeight);
    int diff = Math.abs(leftHeight - rightHeight);

    // check if difference in height is more than 1
    if (diff > 1)
        return false;

    // check if left and right subtrees are balanced
    else 
        return isBalanced(root.left) && isBalanced(root.right);
```

The part I don't understand is why do we need return isBalanced(root.left) && isBalanced(root.right). Isn't it enough just to check the height and return false if the hight is more than 1, and true otherwise?

Comment: Having equal heights on the left and right root does not guarantee that a tree is balanced. I can, for example, have a root with left height 6 and right height 6, but the left branch is a single branch that does not have any right branches.

Comment: How can you have a tree with more than 3 nodes of the height cannot exceed 1?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it is not enough to *just to check the height and return false if the height is more than 1, and true otherwise*. Simply checking the root's height would result in false positives like the following:

```
        A
       / \
      B   F
     /   /
    C   G
   /   /
  D   H
 /   /
E   I
```